# Access in mounted folder in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Unable to write/modify/create in the mounted folder via docker container

```
docker  run -it --rm -v ${pwd}:/files ubuntu /bin/bash
```

when the docker is running in interactive mode 
Change directory to **files**

```
cd files
```

Now try to write /create directory in mounted folder ('files')

```
mkdir test
```

you get ERROR :

```
mkdir: cannot create directory 'ff': Permission denied
```

How to overcome that error:??

Comment: Please add more about what OS you are using and which docker product/version you are using.

Comment: windows 10 and Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962 @spender

Comment: are you able to replicate it? @spender

Comment: Did you follow this? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: From your host's console, can you echo the value of ${pwd}?

Comment: Any updates @kunalverma ?

Comment: @spender  tried with all images ubuntu , node etc if i  mount a folder and try to execute any mkdir  or cat inside the mounted folder gets error...searched entire net seen similar issues but no resolution.....

Comment: @Mihai  its the mounted folder i.e /files    >>>if i  cd  .. then /